# Como forçar o login após rodar a aplicação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, session, autenticação

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

Após a autenticação com o Active Directory, o usuário que efetuou o login é salvo em uma Session

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Usuario, model.Senha))
    {
        Session.Add("Usuario", new UsuarioModel { Nome = "Eu", Login = "Filipe"});
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Usuario, false);
        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "O usuário ou a senha são inválidos");

    return View(model);
}
```

Depois disso eu faço algumas alterações no código e executo a aplicação novamente, mas a Session não permanece lá e a aplicação considera que o usuário ainda está logado.

Como posso limpar esta coisa que faz com que o usuário ainda pareça estar online?

Comment: Mas é para manter o _login_ na sessão e aplicação ou para forçar novo _login_ porque foram feitas alterações ao código?

Comment: @Zuul, forçar o novo login por conta das alterações. Mas manter o login na sessão também seria uma boa, tu tens exemplo disso?

Answer (score 3):

Faça o usuário abandonar a sessão no evento `Application_End` do seu `Global.asax.cs`:

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

PS: Não testei esse código.

---

EDIT

Como o código acima não funcionou, creio que a maneira programática possa não ser uma boa saída. No arquivo `Web.config`, modifique o seguinte:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name="MinhaAutenticacao" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="300"/>
</authentication>
```

- `timeout` confere que o Cookie durará 5 minutos, no máximo, se o usuário ficar ocioso (ou seja, sem fazer qualquer requisição ao servidor);
- [`slidingExpiration` renova a expiração do Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx) caso alguma requisição seja feita dentro dos cinco minutos.

Comment: Sem o OP se manifestar não sei o que ele pretende, mas como já colocaste uma resposta, talvez deixar ambos os cenários expostos na resposta seja melhor, assim tá sempre correto ;)

Comment: Quem votou a negativo nesta resposta, dá para indicar a razão?

Comment: @Zuul É que eu li errado mesmo. Eu entendi que ele queria manter o Cookie, não expirar ele.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, no `Application_End` essa exceção é levantada: `Estado da sessão não está disponível neste contexto.`

Comment: @FilipeOliveira Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a aplicação ainda está considerando que o usuário está logado, mas a `Session` criada no Login não existe mais.